# How to know on what OS/Platform the Postgresql Server runns?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.5

i am trying to write a `SQL` function that determines if the Postgres Server is running on windows, is that possible, or is there a way to get the platform of a running Server?

Comment: `select version()` will include that information (although a bit hard to parse)

Comment: That's probably the best you will get with SQL. Use PL/Perl or PL/Python for something better.

Comment: exactly the problem with  version that it is a little bit hard to parse, but thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `select version()`
I tried it on an Linux Alpine server (through a Docker container) and got this: 
test=> select version();

```
                                             version                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 6.2.1) 6.2.1 20160822, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

You can have more informations on postgres system informations functions here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html

Hope it'll help you !

Comment: I know the version() function and this is what I thought too, i wanted something more specific without parsing, but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I wroteand used at the end, it works great on Postgres 11 version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetPLatform()
RETURNS varchar
AS
$$
 declare platform varchar;
begin  
 SELECT CASE
            WHEN OSVersion.OS LIKE '%w64%' THEN 'windows'
            WHEN OSVersion.OS LIKE '%w32%' THEN 'windows'
            WHEN OSVersion.OS LIKE '%mingw%' THEN 'windows'
            WHEN OSVersion.OS LIKE '%visual studio%' THEN 'windows'
            WHEN OSVersion.OS LIKE '%linux%' THEN 'linux'
            WHEN OSVersion.OS LIKE '%mac%' THEN 'mac'
            ELSE
            'UNKNOWN'
         END into platform
    FROM (SELECT 
            substr(substr(version(), strpos(version(), ' on ')+3), 1, 
            strpos(substr(version(), strpos(version(), ' on ')+3), 
            ', compiled by')-1) as OS) 
    as OSVersion;
    return platform;  
end; 
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

select GetPLatform()
```

You can adjust it as you want for other platforms...

Comment: I did this using your code 
select case when version() like '%linux%' then 'linux' else 'windows' end as flag

Answer (score 0):

Because using mmap is very rare, you can use :

```
SELECT CASE setting 
          WHEN 'windows' THEN 'WINDOWS family'
          WHEN 'posix' THEN 'UNIX family'
          WHEN 'sysv' THEN 'UNIX family'
          ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
       END AS OS_family
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_file_settings
WHERE  name = 'dynamic_shared_memory_type'
```

Another solution could be :

```
SELECT CASE setting
          WHEN '0700' THEN 'Windows'
          ELSE 'UNIX'
       END AS OS_FAMILLY
FROM   pg_settings
WHERE name = 'data_directory_mode'
```

To show the familly of OS between UNIX or Windows...